# digital Countdown from a set time in python

Tags: python, time

I need to create a program that does a digital countdown from a set time. It needs to be printed so it reads Hours:minutes:seconds.

```
import time 
count=int(input("Enter your start point")) 
count2=int(input("Enter your start point")) 
count3=int(input("Enter your start point")) 
while count and count and count3 >0: 
    time.sleep(1)   
    print(count,+":",+":",+count3) 
    count -=1 
    count2 -=1 
    count3 -=1
```

Comment: Please share what you tried...

Comment: import time
count=int(input("Enter your start point"))
count2=int(input("Enter your start point"))
count3=int(input("Enter your start point"))

while count and count and count3 >0: 
    time.sleep(1)
    print(count,+":",+":",+count3)
    count -=1
    count2 -=1
    count3 -=1

Comment: Please update your question with the code you tried . So that you can not receive dislike.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time


hours = 1
minutes = 0
seconds = 4

while not hours==minutes==seconds==0:
    print str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)+":"+str(seconds)
    time.sleep(1)
    if minutes==seconds==0:
        hours-=1
        minutes=59
        seconds=59
    elif seconds==0:
        minutes-=1
        seconds=59
    else:
        seconds-=1
```

Try this. Can add padding to the numbers if required. Here is the POC.

```
>>1:0:4
>>1:0:3
>>1:0:2
>>1:0:1
>>1:0:0
>>0:59:59
>>0:59:58
>>0:59:57
>>0:59:56
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code ,this will produce your required output.
Please let me know in terms of any query,

```
import time 
count=int(input("Enter your start point")) 
count2=int(input("Enter your start point")) 
count3=int(input("Enter your start point")) 

while count | count2 | count3 >0: 
    while(count>=0):
        while(count2>=0):
            while(count3>=0):
                time.sleep(1) 
                print count,":",count2,":",+count3
                count3 -= 1
            count3 = 59
            count2 -= 1
        count2 = 59
        count -= 1
```

In your old code AND operator is used , so it will terminate theexecution even if any variable is zero.
Output:

```
1 : 0 : 4
1 : 0 : 3
1 : 0 : 2
1 : 0 : 1
1 : 0 : 0
0 : 59 : 59
0 : 59 : 58
0 : 59 : 57
0 : 59 : 56
0 : 59 : 55
0 : 59 : 54
0 : 59 : 53
0 : 59 : 52
```